# ReactNative -ios - PencilKit's ToolPicker only show on application resume

Tags: ios, react-native, pencilkit

I'm following this tutorial of building React native app using Apple's PencilKit:
https://blog.logrocket.com/build-react-native-drawing-app-pencilkit/

The project I'm trying to run:
https://github.com/hrupesh/RNPencilKit.git

but on the last step of adding ToolPicker, I was baffled to find out the ToolPicker only shows when I send the app to the background and resume it. I'm not familiar with React native so any help will be much appreciated!

Here is the code that called the ToolPicker:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const drawingRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
        findNodeHandle(drawingRef?.current),
        UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('PencilKit').Commands.setupToolPicker,
        undefined,
      );
    }, 400);
  }, []);
```

```
-(void) setupToolPicker(
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self->_toolPicker = [[PKToolPicker alloc] init];
        [self->_toolPicker setVisible:true forFirstResponder:self->_canvasView];
        [self->_toolPicker addObserver:self->_canvasView];
        [self->_toolPicker addObserver:self]:
        [self->_canvasView becomeFirstResponder];
        self->_undoManager = [[self->_canvasView undoManager] init]:
        NSLOg(@"Set Toolpicker");
        NSLog(self->_toolPicker.isVisible ? @"yes" : @"NO"):
        NSLog(self->_canvasview.isFirstResponder ? @"isFirstResponder: yes" : @"isFirstResponder: No");
    ]);
}
```

both _toolPicker.isVisible and _canvasview.isFirstResponder logged out to be "Yes"

Also, I'm running on ios's stimulator iphone 14 pro - ios 16.4 if that could be the issue.

Thanks in advance!